# When would you not want to subscribe to an observable in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I came across the difference between Observables and Promises in Angular. One of the advantages is that observables are "lazy," in that it would only make the call if subscribed to. But, when would you not want to subscribe to an observable?

Answer (score 0):

Image a service which does stuff like

```
interface Foo {
  id: number;
}
public loadStuffFromApiEndpoint(): Observable<Foo> {
   return this.http.get<Foo>('...')
}
```

Now if u need to add a e.g. timestamp to the response from the server which u want to use in two different spots u can imagine another service function like

```
interface FooExtended extends Foo {
  createdAt: number;
}
public loadAndEnrichStuffFromApiEndpoint(): Observable<FooExtended> {
  return this.loadStuffFromApiEndpoint().pipe(map(e => e.loadedAt: Date.now()))
}
```

That way u don't subscribe to the Observable but rather you are going to pipe it to enrich it.